# Symfony 3.3 : 2 form of same type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, frameworks

I have a big form in my web site. Because it's very big, I want to split it in two part. I've done the first one and it's working. Now I want to do the second one on the same page. Both of them have the same entity (so basically, I want to do 2 form of a same entity on the same page) but I don't now how to do that in the buildForm. Do I need to create another variable next to $builder ($builder = my first form).

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Can you please show some code to make it easier to understand what you want? Do you still display both forms on the same page? Do both forms have a submit button? If not, do you save your entity between pages or store the data in session/cache?

Answer (score 0):

Here some code :

```
class myType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('numero')
                ->add('other')
                ->add('things')
    }
```

I want to have 1 submit button form 2 form, but the second for is not display in the first time. It will be displayed only if the first form is submitted.

Comment: (please update your question with this clarification, rather than posting it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, and I dont know if it is the best way, but I would create two form types. 1) a formtype based on your entity and 2) a fromtype where you bring them together.

A simple example for a contact

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('billing', AddressType::class);
    $builder->add('shipping', AddressType::class);       
}

public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return 'contact';
}
}
```

The AddressType would look like :

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('street', TextType::class, array())
            ->add('country', TextType::class, array())
            ;
}

public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return 'address';
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) 
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => '<yourbundle>\Entity\Address',
    ));
}
}
```